# Why should I use a container for storing observers?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

It is said here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx#observerpattern_topic3a

> This permits a subject to notify a
>   potentially infinite number of
>   observers of state changes, rather
>   than just one.

Why can't I just use

```
list<Observer>
```

in the subject class instead of delegating to a container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list<Observer>` collection **is** the container that the article refers to. It is an implementation detail whether you chose a list, a map, a set, etc. to hold the set of `Observer`s. It really is up to you what to use. The pattern won't change depending on the type of container used.

Comment: Typically and unless the OP has very special needs, in Java observers are indeed done using a *List<Observer>* whose not-so-detail implementation is typically a "COWAL" (CopyOnWriteArrayList).  It's not that much a detail for obvious synchronization and performance reasons (as explained in *Java Concurrency In Practice*).

Answer (score 1):

Your List data structure is a container :)

That sentence is simply distinguishing between maintaining a `List<Observer>` data structure (for example) and a single Observer reference.

EDIT: Looks like I was beaten to the punch

Comment: Well I thought container was meaning something more sophisticated :)